# Deploying Rails applications with Passenger Enterprise "Mass Deployment" feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

We're thinking about purchasing a license for Passenger Enterprise, and I'm looking for a better explanation about the "Mass Deployment" feature in Passenger Enterprise Edition.

Say you have Rails 3 applications -

- my_blog
- news_site
- online_resume

These all get dropped into a directory on the server, and we can point Passenger to look at that directory and serve up those applications.

So my question is: How does nginx come in to play here? Is the nginx configuration for that virtual server completely ignored? We often need to upgrade nginx config for things like rewrites, as well as some passenger configuration (min_instances, for example).

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the Passenger Mass Deployment video on [Phusion website](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/enterprise) I suspect the mass deployment option only is available with Passenger Standalone, and not with the Passenger Nginx module.

One option is to use Passenger Standalone (`$ passenger start`) and use Nginx as a reverse proxy by using the `proxy_pass` directive, as illustrated in this ["Phusion Passenger & running multiple Ruby versions"](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/) blog post by the Phusion team. Here's the relevant Nginx configuration snippet taken from that post:

```
# Partial Nginx configuration
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.fries.com;
    root /webapps/fries.com/public;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Currently documentation on this feature seems to be non-existent, except for the aforementioned product video. There's a high resolution version available on [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/46042771).

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for the documentation on this myself and thought I'd mention it here for future searchers.

[Phusion Passenger Standalone: Mass Deployment](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html#mass_deployment)